# Remove a running thread from a hashmap

Tags: java

I have a hashmap, i want to remove a specific running thread from it, and i want the thread to continue to do some process and then it will be destroyed, anyone knows what happens when the running thread is removed from hashmap?

Comment: A reference to a `Thread` is no different from a any other reference type in *Java*.

Comment: So u mean the Thread will not continue processing and garbage collector will get rid of it?

Comment: Yes. Provided the `Thread` is not referenced from anywhere else and the `Thread` has finished executing it's `run` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> anyone knows what happens when the running thread is removed from hashmap?

The thread will continue running, until it finishes its `run` method. In another words, it will finish when it is done.

Reference: [Life cycle of a thread in Java](http://www.javatpoint.com/life-cycle-of-a-thread)

---

Extra:

The same happens in the following example.

```
new Thread(runnableObject).start();
```

This thread will run in the background until `runnableObject` terminates.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all.

Answer (score 1):

Agree, your thread will continue running until the method **run()** end.

Try this code :

```
    //Create the HashMap
    HashMap<String, Thread> map = new HashMap<String, Thread>();

    //Create a task
    Runnable task = () -> {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Tick " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    //Create a thread with the task
    Thread t = new Thread(task);

    //Add this thread into the map
    map.put("KEY", t);

    //Start this thread
    t.start();

    //Add this thread into the map
    map.remove("KEY");
```

Comment: I am not having any problem in my code, my program is working fine.